# "Created by" field of CiviMail pulls the name of the latest subscriber

Tags: civimail, 4.6

I am a new user of CiviCRM. My organisation uses CiviCRM 4.6.36. and I have a small problem: for some reason, CiviMail shows the name of the latest subscriber in the "created by" field when I create an email. It is not a big issue but causes some confusion. I went through the settings but was unable to resolve the issue. My question is: what might cause the problem?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

CiviCRM 4.6 has not been supported for some time. It has known security issues and PHP compatibility issues.

There may still be people in the community with CiviCRM 4.6 sites who can assist in troubleshooting but you should absolutely raise within your organisation that they should be upgrading CiviCRM to a supported version.

The end of life for CiviCRM 4.6 and 4.7 was announced on 2018-12-02 here: https://civicrm.org/blog/josh/extended-security-release-update

Comment: You are absolutely right, I will definitely discuss this.

Comment: There are also new features and improvements in CiviCRM 5.x that address things organisations have been asking for, for years :-) Like Themes - we have around 6 community-contributed Themes that make CiviCRM much more user friendly :-)